# Is their any performance issue if I am storing different length data of 1d and 2d barcode UPC's in different column datatypes?

Tags: java, oracle, barcode, qr-code

I have done scanning of firstly 1d barcode in java.Now as I am trying to do scanning of 2d barcode. After scanning the 2d barcode I will compare that scanned value with the one in database. I want to know Is their any performance issue if I am storing different length data of 1d and 2d barcode UPC's in different column data types or same column data types?

Comment: what are you comparing? The image? That's probably wrong. You have to parse the content of the bar code and compare and store that.

Comment: @simas_ch : I am not comparing the image . I am comparing the scanned value. Suppose it has some alphanumeric value (e.g. A12FR56). Now suppose in database I have this value stored earlier. The value which is stored earlier in database is of CLOB datatype. What I am asking is Can I store 1d barcode  and 2d barcode {Both are alphanumeric and of variable size [1d can contain of 22 characters and 2D can contain 4500 characters]} in same column in oracle database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can definitely store the values of different barcodes in the same column of a database. If you store them as simple strings/text you'll have an easy time storing and retrieving them for comparison.
If you need the barcode as an image again, you should recreate it from the string - you may need an additional column to identify the type of barcode you want though.

Comment: Actually the problem is length of both the barcode's UPC vlaues [1d barcode UPC is of max 22 characters and 2d barcode UPC is of  4500 characters max] .So is my above question .

Comment: So, define the column as max_length text and just store it there. It doesn't hinder comparisons in any ways if the difference is length is gigantic.

Comment: If I use two seperate fields to store 1d barcode UPC and 2d barcode UPC.Would it affect any performance ? IF it affects ,how can it be? Also,if I store both in same fields, what is the performance of my software then?